# What online sites are available to help organize redundant error/cron emails?

Tags: email

I feel like I saw a site somewhere that would "dedupe" error messages commonly sent from frameworks like Django or cron errors. I cannot seem to re-find the site however. Have people heard of online tools like this that help wade through the hundreds of emails applications can possibly send at times?

Answer (score 4):

Though it's not an online service, this problem can be solved by running your syslogs through [tenshi](http://dev.inversepath.com/trac/tenshi).

Instead of hundreds of duplicate notifications you get what amounts to a summary of the number of times a particular event occurred over a configurable time period on particular systems.

Comment: +1 i would suggest some sort of log monitoring tool, this is the first time i've heard of `tenshi` but it, or any of the slew of other tools out there for monitoring logs would be ideal for this.